# AVPlayerItem's status changes to AVPlayerItemStatusFailed every time after first failure

Tags: ios, avplayer

I am trying to play a movie file of .mp4 format using AVPlayer. In my code, I am creating AVPlayer every time whenever a movie play is requested. Everything works fine except if due AVPlayer fails to play a movie once then in every next play request it fails until application is launched again.

I key value observing AVPlayerItem's status property for detecting AVPlayer failure.

Has anyone come across similar kind of problem?

Thanks in Advance.

I get this error from AVPlayerItem's error property:

`Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 "The operation could not be completed" UserInfo=0x17946d540 {NSUnderlyingError=0x178642dc0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -12983.)", NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred (-12983), NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could not be completed}`

Comment: You need to post some code.